# Updating part of a SQL cell

Tags: sql

Trying to run this SQL script

```
update Promotions
   set PromotionDiscountData = '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="StartDatePromotionRule"><StartDate>2013-11-11T00:00:00</StartDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationDatePromotionRule"><ExpirationDate>2014-01-12T00:00:00</ExpirationDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationNumberOfUsesPerCustomerPromotionRule"><NumberOfUsesAllowed>1</NumberOfUsesAllowed></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ProductIdPromotionRule"><ProductIds><int>55232</int></ProductIds><RequireQuantity>false</RequireQuantity><Quantity>1</Quantity><AndTogether>false</AndTogether></PromotionRuleBase></ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase>'
 where PromotionDiscountData = '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="StartDatePromotionRule"><StartDate>2013-11-18T00:00:00</StartDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationDatePromotionRule"><ExpirationDate>2014-01-12T00:00:00</ExpirationDate></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationNumberOfUsesPerCustomerPromotionRule"><NumberOfUsesAllowed>1</NumberOfUsesAllowed></PromotionRuleBase><PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ProductIdPromotionRule"><ProductIds><int>55232</int></ProductIds><RequireQuantity>false</RequireQuantity><Quantity>1</Quantity><AndTogether>false</AndTogether></PromotionRuleBase></ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase>'
```

but getting this error

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

any idea how to fix this?

Basically within each cell I am trying to change the StartDate only

Comment: Witch database are you using? It seems that your database type of PromotionDiscountData is xml and you cannot handle it as string. Also, you can update your table by primary key, if you have one.

Comment: its AspDotNetStoreFront running on a Win 2008 Server.

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but try something along lines of "select ... where cast(PromotionDiscountData as varchar(max)) = ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the type of PromotionDiscountData column is XML, so that's why I suggest you to use the following code snippet:

```
update Promotions
set PromotionDiscountData = '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase ...'
where CAST(PromotionDiscountData as NVARCHAR(MAX)) = '<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase...'
```

Comment: Getting there :) It somehow changed the date, but not to the value I wanted but instead used the current datestamp and time. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though

Comment: Note that this is likely to need to run a table scan (read through the entire table) due to casting the column in the table.  If possible, cast the _incoming data_ to the matching type.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: very good remark, anyway cast of string to XML doesn't help due to limitations of XML data type: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107(v=sql.90).aspx. As alternative, the WHERE clause should use done using PK for row identification.